# Using Arduino Click shield with NDIR Click CO2

Tags: arduino-mega, shields

I am trying to use  ([NDIR CO2 sensor Mikroelectronika](https://www.mikroe.com/ndir-co2-click)) with Arduino Mega 2560 utilizing the Click shield.

Mikroelectronika provides libraries for their platform (likely proprietary), hence i have no idea how to manage to do this with arduino.

Here is the code I tried from the [library page](https://libstock.mikroe.com/projects/view/3625/ndir-co2-click).

```
void application_init ( void )
{
log_cfg_t log_cfg;
ndirco2_cfg_t cfg;

//  Logger initialization.

log_cfg.level = LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG;
LOG_MAP_USB_UART( log_cfg );
log_init( &logger, &log_cfg );
log_info( &logger, "---- Application Init ----" );

//  Click initialization.

ndirco2_cfg_setup( &cfg );
NDIRCO2_MAP_MIKROBUS( cfg, MIKROBUS_1 );
ndirco2_init( &ndirco2, &cfg );

Delay_ms( 300 );

ndirco2_reset( &ndirco2 );
ndirco2_write_register( &ndirco2, NDIRCO2_AVERAGING_COUNT_REG, 0x03 );
ndirco2_set_mode( &ndirco2, NDIRCO2_CONTINUOUS_OP_MODE );
log_printf( &logger, "NDIR CO2 is initialized \r\n" );
Delay_ms( 200 ); 
}


void application_task ( )
{
uint16_t co2_data;

ndirco2_read_co2( &ndirco2, NDIRCO2_CHECK_EACH_MEASURE, &co2_data );
log_printf( &logger, "CO2 concentration is: %d ppm \r\n", co2_data );
}
```

**The example for arduino is [available here](https://www.mikroe.com/arduino-uno-click-shield).**